# Regular Expression in R: disentangling similar possibilities

Tags: r, regex, replace

I have a list of names looking like this

```
Noms<- c("André Coin", "XXXAndré Coin", "Gabriel Péri","Léon Blum", "XXXLéon Blum")
```

I am trying to create a function that finds each time when each of these names is found in a very long text, at the beginning of a line starting with "M" or "Mme".

My text is a vector in which each line is an element.

So at the end, a line like `"M. André Coin said bla bla"` would be matched; but a line like `"He said bla bla bla to M. André Coin"` would NOT be matched.

The final requirement is that "André Coin" can be distinguished from "XXXAndré Coin".

The solution I have found for the moment is:

```
findpattern <- function(name,vect) {
    x<-paste0("^.{1,3}((M\\s*)|(Mme\\s*))*\\s*",name)
    found<-grepl(x,vect)
    return(found)
    }
```

However, when I run `findpattern(Noms,txt)`, it cannot distinguish "André Coin" from "XXX André Coin". Meaning that `findpattern("André Coin", "M. XXXAndré Coin")=TRUE".`
Can you help me find my mistake in the writing of my regular expression?

Comment: I tried entering your function and `findpattern("André Coin", "M. XXXAndré Coin")` and the result is `FALSE`...

Comment: Indeed... I am pretty sure I copied the exact same code as before tough. I guess some typo solved the problem somehow

Answer (score 0):

You've missed a dot after the `M` and the 3 first characters must be optionnal (ie. form 0 to 3 char):

```
"^.{0,3}((M\\.\\s*)|(Mme\\s*))*\\s*"
```

If the dot after `M` is optionnal:

```
"^.{0,3}((M\\.?\\s*)|(Mme\\s*))*\\s*"
```